# Android : Bound service handling multiple messages simultaneously from client

Tags: android, multithreading, service, messenger

Here is my problem :
To simplify I use an IntentService that handles a couple a message using a Messenger object, a first message (msg.what==1) launch a 10 sec process, the second one (msg.what==2) launch a 5 sec process. These messages are sent by a third party Activity which is bound to my service, and which is waiting for a reply to these sent messages.

Everything works fine but if the message 1 is running, when sending the message 2, it'll wait until the first process is done to be processed. As I read this the expected behavior with Intent Service (messages are queued and processed sequentially in an external thread).

**But is there a trick to get an asynchronous response to a new sent message when the previous one is still running ?** (ie get a reply to message 2 when message 1 is still running) I tried using thread and asynctask on my handleMessage function with no success (I even don't get any answer to my request in the activity)

**Service class : Handler**

```
    class IncomingHanlder extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)  {
        try {
            switch (msg.what) {

                case 1:
                    //Process taking 10 sec
                    //...

                    //Reply to client
                    Message resp = Message.obtain(null, msg.what);
                    Bundle bResp = new Bundle();
                    bResp.putBoolean("com.xxx.msg1", true);
                    resp.setData(bResp);
                    msg.replyTo.send(resp);
                    break;

                case 2:
                    //Process taking 5 sec
                    //...

                    //Reply to client
                    Message resp = Message.obtain(null, msg.what);
                    Bundle bResp = new Bundle();
                    bResp.putBoolean("com.xxx.msg2", true);
                    resp.setData(bResp);
                    msg.replyTo.send(resp);
                    break;

                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
            catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

private Messenger msg = new Messenger(new IncomingHanlder ());

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {return msg.getBinder();}
```

**Client class : activity (third party application)**

```
ServiceConnection sConn = new ServiceConnection() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                messenger = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                // We are connected to the service
                messenger = new Messenger(service);
            }
        };

        // We bind to the service
        Intent i = new Intent("com.xxx.myserviceboundpackage");
        try {
            //If service is always launched
            stopService(i);
        }
        catch (Exception e){}

        //Bind to service
        bindService(i, sConn,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

**In client : sending a message from clicking a button (for example message 1)**

```
                try {
                Message msg = Message
                        .obtain(null, 1);

                msg.replyTo = new Messenger(new ResponseHandler());;

                try {
                    messenger.send(msg);
                } catch (RemoteException e) {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printstacktrace();
            }
```

**In client : handling a message from service reply to**

```
    class ResponseHanlder extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)  {
        try {
            switch (msg.what) {

                //Response to each request
                case 1:
                    //Process which have taken 10 sec

                    Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
                    Boolean myResp = bundle.getBoolean("com.xxx.msg1");
                    if (myResp) {//do something}
                    break;

                case 2:
                    //Process which have taken 5 sec

                    Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
                    Boolean myResp = bundle.getBoolean("com.xxx.msg2");
                    if (myResp) {//do something}
                    break;

                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
            catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: Juste imagine I send message 1, and immediatelyI send message 2 from my activity. The message 2 is not handled immediately, it's queued. So I get it's response after 10sec (handling message 1) + 5 sec (handling message 2 that has been queued). I would like to get my response to message 2 after 5 sec only (without waiting for message 1 process is finished)

Comment: it is queued since you are using `IntentService` that uses one background thread for all requests, if you want to process your messages immediately use `"one Message - one Thread"` approach

Comment: Can you give me examples if this kind of approach using bilateral dialog between an activity and service ?

Comment: see http://pastebin.com/L1m3NJTT

Comment: Thanks I try it and I come back !

Comment: Ok I've read the example code, and if I understand it correctly, when binding from client side you get a B class (that has to be known by the client) and you can start your long running process using something like : myBobject.runSomething(100); Is there a way to achieve the same kind of logic using messenger withing a service class ? I mean keeping the shape of my code : activity send message to service which handles it in a threadpool then process it and reply as soon it's finished, allowing other messages to be handled in parallel task ?

Comment: sure: call `pool.submit` inside `handleMessage`

Answer (score 0):

Ok considering pskink's link (http://pastebin.com/L1m3NJTT)

Here is what I tried : I now extends Service and no more IntentService. And my Handler is now

```
class IncomingHanlder extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)  {
        pool.submit(new MyRunnable(msg));
        super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

This method has to get the incoming message (msg) in order be allowed using the replyto method, in myRunnable method which is

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
private final Message _message;
public MyRunnable(final Message message) {
    this._message = message;
}


@Override
public void run() {
try {
    switch (this._message.what) {

        case 1:
            //Process taking 10 sec
            //...

            //Reply to client
            Message resp = Message.obtain(null, this._message.what);
            Bundle bResp = new Bundle();
            bResp.putBoolean("com.xxx.msg1", true);
            resp.setData(bResp);
            this._message.replyTo.send(resp);
            break;

        case 2:
            //Process taking 5 sec
            //...

            //Reply to client
            Message resp = Message.obtain(null, this._message.what);
            Bundle bResp = new Bundle();
            bResp.putBoolean("com.xxx.msg2", true);
            resp.setData(bResp);
            this._message.replyTo.send(resp);
            break;

        default:

    }
}
    catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Note that I still use for the Service Interface onBind implementation:

```
private Messenger msg = new Messenger(new ConvertHanlder());

  @Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return msg.getBinder();
}
```

**The fact is : I never get any answer in activity on sending message now. Did I miss something ?**